# Makefile automatic rule dependency generation depends on another rule dependency generation

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am using two programming languages together. A compiler takes program written with the first language (the source language) and translates them into the second language (the target language, for me, the C language). There are a few files generated this way, and also hand-written ones. Finally, i compile all these file (in the target language) into executable code.

I managed to generate automatically dependency files (classically named .d files) for the source language, to tell Makefile (I'm using GNU Makefile) in which order and when to call the first compiler. (Order is important for this compiler.) I also know how to generate dependencies for the target language (using GCC). I use the include directive to automatically include all dependencies. Makefile will find which rule to call to generate dependency files and include them.

Makefile works in three phases. First, it includes everything already generated. Second, it generate missing includes if possible. Third, it tries to build the target.

Now, to generate automatically the dependencies for the target language, I first need to generate all the files (since some generated headers are included) using the first compiler.

Here is the problem, in the second phase: when Makefile will want to generate the dependency files for the target code, it will first try to generate this target code from the source code. But, even if it has generated dependency for the source code, it didn't load these dependencies yet (dependencies will only be read at the end of this phase). So it will fail to compile the source code, since it is generally dependent of the order of compilation.

Is there a way to solve this problem ? Can Makefile be instructed to include generated dependencies as soon are they are generated ? Is there a way to alter the "3 phase" behavior of Makefile ?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your file in the target language is `foo.c` and this is generated from `foo.x`. Your dependencies for `foo.c` are in a file `foo.d`. Suppose the dependencies for `foo.x` are in `foo.xd`.

If you run `make foo.c`, it appears that you have a rule for building or rebuilding `foo.d` which either appears in `foo.d` itself, or in the main makefile. It looks like `foo.d` depends on `foo.xd`, which doesn't exist yet (or `foo.d` depends on `foo.c`, which depends on `foo.xd`.) If I understand correctly, `foo.xd` cannot be built for some reason (something to do with the order that `make` is processing the makefile).

You might be able to build `foo.d` in a different way that doesn't depend on `foo.xd`. Can it depend on `foo.c` alone?

I'm not sure how relevant it is to the question, but it may be worth noting that dependency files are not needed the first time a file is built - if it doesn't exist, it has to be built and its dependencies don't matter.

Comment: It is not useful to generate dependency files the first time you build... unless the order of build is relevant. Here, i need to build foo.xd before being able to build foo.c, because to build foo.c i may need to build several dependencies first.

Comment: Are the other dependencies `*.x` files? So you don't know what source language files are needed to produce a target language file?

Comment: The other dependencies are derived from *.x files. You are right: i don't know what source files are needed to produce a target file.

Comment: It seems there are two separate problems: when a target file should be rebuilt (makefile dependencies), and in fact *how* it should be built.  Usually for automatic dependency tracking, you only have the first problem. Dependency files for `*.c` files (I called them `*.d`) are not actually read by the C compiler. But it seems that your dependencies for the source files (`*.x`) are being read by whatever program produces the `*.c` files? Are you sure it is right to use what I called `*.xd` (you called them `*.d`) for both purposes?

Comment: I am pretty sure of that. Make achieved to solve the two questions  "when to remake" and "in which order" with the same dependency mechanism. What is not obvious from what i explained here, is that there is another type of file, let's call them *.y. A %.x is compiled into %.y and %.c, but may depend on **other** %.y. This means that %.x have to be compiled in an appropriate order.

Comment: This is hard to understand. Can you post some code that shows the principles of the problem?